# Boost geometry: point on track

Tags: boost-geometry

I have two points A and B on a sphere (or a WGS84 ellipsoid, if using the geographic extension). These two points define a great circle.
I wish to find the coordinates of a point M on that great circle, lying at a certain distance from A (going from A to B).

To give an example application: a boat goes from A to B on a great circle:  knowing its speed I wish to know its position at a given time.

Any way of doing this with boost-geometry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://marc.info/?l=boost&m=126956891713360&w=2) explains that (currently), Boost's geographical functionalities are limited. The [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net) library provides a viable alternative I think.